# Integrate $\int \frac{x^7}{(x^{10} + x^6 + x^2 +1)} dx$

Tags: integration

How I can integrate this $$\int \frac{x^7}{(x^{10} + x^6 + x^2 +1)} dx$$

Comment: Please show what you have done or tried so far and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor an answer to your background and situation. It also demonstrates that you aren't just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be pleasant, since the denominator is irreducible over the rationals.  You could write it as

$$\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_r \dfrac{r^3 \ln(x^2-r)}{5 r^4 + 3 r^2 + 1}$$

where the sum is over the five roots (one real, two complex-conjugate pairs) of $z^5 + z^3 + z + 1$.